# Read Numeric Data from a Text File in C++

Tags: c++

For example, if data in an external text file is like this:

```
45.78   67.90   87
34.89   346     0.98
```

How can I read this text file and assign each number to a variable in c++?
Using ifstream, I am able to open the text file and assign first number to a variable, but I don't know how to read the next number after the spaces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("data.txt");
    myfile >> a;
    cout << a;
    myfile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int data[6], a, b, c, d, e, f;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("a.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i << 6; i++)
        myfile >> data[i];

    myfile.close();
    a = data[0];
    b = data[1];
    c = data[2];
    d = data[3];
    e = data[4];
    f = data[5];
    cout << a << "\t" << b << "\t" << c << "\t" << d << "\t" << e << "\t" << f << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your text file contains *floats*, but you try to read them into *int array* (). That won't work as you expect. The question is very unclear, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe write your input and output you expect to be returned.

Comment: @Spook : the simple description of my problem is " A text file contains numbers in  100 rows  * 100 columns (for example). Now i want my program to pick up ,for example , one number from 60th row and 97th column and then assign this value to a variable and perform some calculation with this variable. So i want to pick up some random numbers from a text file which contains a lot of numbers. how can i do that ?? thanks for patient replies :)

Comment: @spook : I am interested in your first solution but the problem is how should i skip certain number of values and pick up the required one ?? I mean i can do that with a loop but in that case my array would be very large. I want that my array should contain only those values (out of thousands in text file) in which i am interested in !!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Repeat >> reads in loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("D:\\data.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    float a;
    while (myfile >> a)
    {
        printf("%f ", a);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

`45.779999 67.900002 87.000000 34.889999 346.000000 0.980000`

If you know *exactly*, how many elements there are in a file, you can chain >> operator:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("D:\\data.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    float a, b, c, d, e, f;

    myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f;

    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", a, b, c, d, e, f);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit:** In response to your comments in main question.

You have two options.

- You can run previous code in a loop (or two loops) and throw away a defined number of values - for example, if you need the value at point (97, 60), you have to skip 5996 (= 60 * 100 + 96) values and use the last one. This will work if you're interested *only* in specified value.
- You can load the data into an array - as Jerry Coffin sugested. He already gave you quite nice class, which will solve the problem. Alternatively, you can use simple array to store the data.

---

**Edit:** How to skip values in file

To choose the 1234th value, use the following code:

```
int skipped = 1233;
for (int i = 0; i < skipped; i++)
{
    float tmp;
    myfile >> tmp;
}
myfile >> value;
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. but i want to store these numbers in different variables. Should i first read all the numbers with a loop and store them into an array and then assign differnt elements of this array to variables ??

Comment: Remember to mark one of answers as accepted if it fits your needs. Otherwise don't hesitate to add comments if something needs to be cleared up.

Comment: #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {int data[6],a,b,c,d,e,f;
 ifstream myfile;
 myfile.open ("a.txt");
 for (int i=0;i<<6;i++)
 {
  myfile>>data[i];
    }
 myfile.close();
 a=data[0];
 b=data[1];
 c=data[2];
 d=data[3];
 e=data[4];
 f=data[5];
 cout<<a<<"\t"<<b<<"\t"<<c<<"\t"<<d<<"\t"<<e<<"\t"<<f<<"\n";
 system ("pause");
 return 0;}

Comment: Why didn't you use my second solution? Also, if you want to enter some code, edit your post rather than input it in comment. You pasted some code, where's the problem with it?

Comment: @spook.. your second solution was very helpful. The last step in my problem is i want to read different digits from a text (which i have succeeded with your suggestion) and then putt them into an array and assigning different elements of the array a different variable so that i cud perform some calculation with these variables.

Comment: but with this code, i am not getting the output numbers which were there in my file..rather getting a repeated number, probably an error !! -858993640 -858993640 ,,,,,

Comment: I just wonder that if we don't know the number of numbers each line, how can we read the file line by line using `>>` or `<<` ?

Comment: What if we don't know how many numbers we have per line? can we read it into a vector?

Comment: Don't you want to check if the file exists? And do you have to close the file stream?

Answer (score 9):

It can depend, especially on whether your file will have the same number of items on each row or not. If it will, then you probably want a 2D matrix class of some sort, usually something like this:

```
class array2D { 
    std::vector<double> data;
    size_t columns;
public:
    array2D(size_t x, size_t y) : columns(x), data(x*y) {}

    double &operator(size_t x, size_t y) {
       return data[y*columns+x];
    }
};
```

Note that as it's written, this assumes you know the size you'll need up-front. That can be avoided, but the code gets a little larger and more complex.

In any case, to read the numbers and maintain the original structure, you'd typically read a line at a time into a string, then use a stringstream to read numbers from the line. This lets you store the data from each line into a separate row in your array.

If you don't know the size ahead of time or (especially) if different rows might not all contain the same number of numbers:

```
11 12 13
23 34 56 78
```

You might want to use a `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` instead. This does impose some overhead, but if different rows may have different sizes, it's an easy way to do the job.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > numbers;

std::string temp;

while (std::getline(infile, temp)) {
    std::istringstream buffer(temp);
    std::vector<double> line((std::istream_iterator<double>(buffer)),
                             std::istream_iterator<double>());

    numbers.push_back(line);
}
```

...or, with a modern (C++11) compiler, you can use brackets for `line`'s initialization:

```
    std::vector<double> line{std::istream_iterator<double>(buffer),
                             std::istream_iterator<double>()};
```

Comment: bundle of thanks..but it will take some time for me to understand your reply :)

Comment: @UsmanNaseer: Perhaps the sample code I just added will be helpful.

Comment: Very nice, +1. That's what I call an idiomatic C++ solution.

Comment: All nice, but it doesn't have much to do with OP's problem - from what he wrote in comments, he wants to read each number into different variable... if I understood his last version correctly.

Comment: I have got this error for the code: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<double> >::push_back(std::vector<double> (&)(std::istream_iterator<double>, std::istream_iterator<double> (*)()))’

Comment: @user1436187: Sorry, there was a typo that led to the most vexing parse. I believe it's now corrected.

Comment: @JerryCoffin can even use `std::vector<double> line{std::istream_iterator<double>(buffer),{})`, replacing  `std::istream_iterator<double>()` with `{}`.

Answer (score 7):

The input operator for number skips leading whitespace, so you can just read the number in a loop:

```
while (myfile >> a)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks. but the input operator reads the number row wise. how can i read the number in next column ??

Comment: @UsmanNaseer: with the loop suggested in this answer, the first time the loop is entered `a` will be 45.78, the next time 67.90, then 87, then 34.89, 346, and the final time 0.98.  Is that not what you need?

Comment: @UsmanNaseer Remember that the file is a _stream_, and the data as seen by the program is in rows or columns, but a single stream like this: `"45.78   67.90   87\n34.89   346     0.98"`. So the input operation will always read the next number in the stream, in "column" order so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

you could read and write to a seperately like others.
But if you want to write into the same one, you could try with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double data[size of your data];

    std::ifstream input("file.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < size of your data; i++) {
        input >> data[i];
        std::cout<< data[i]<<std::endl;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **2D `vector`** for storing the numbers that you read from the text file as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
int main() {
    std::string line;
    double word;

    
    std::ifstream inFile("data.txt");
    
    //create/use a std::vector
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
    
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            //create a temporary vector that will contain all the columns
            std::vector<double> tempVec;
            
            
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            //read word by word(or double by double) 
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                //std::cout<<"word:"<<word<<std::endl;
                //add the word to the temporary vector 
                tempVec.push_back(word);
            
            }      
            
            //now all the words from the current line has been added to the temporary vector 
            vec.emplace_back(tempVec);
        }    
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    inFile.close();
    
    //lets check out the elements of the 2D vector so the we can confirm if it contains all the right elements(rows and columns)
    for(std::vector<double> &newvec: vec)
    {
        for(const double &elem: newvec)
        {
            std::cout<<elem<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/bPgxN0y0H).