# Read doubles out of .txt file into double array c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm attempting to create a program that takes a large number of stock prices. I have these prices stored in a .txt file with one double per row. There are an unknown number (probably thousands). I cannot get the data into an array which I can manipulate. I've been unable to solve this problem for a couple hours now. Whenever I attempt to read the data out of the file and then convert it to a double, I get weird thread errors and the program hangs. Can anyone show me how to read an unknown amount of doubles into an array.

```
string line;
vector<double> doubles;

fstream myfile ("/Users/jaychinnaswamy/Documents/PMHistory.txt",std::ios_base::in);

int x=0;
float a;
while (myfile >> a)
{
    doubles[x]=a;
}
```

An example of the file structure is:

50.4000000000000

50.8000000000000

50.5000000000000

50.2100000000000

49.1500000000000

48.5000000000000

Thanks

Comment: Show us code you have tried.

Comment: google has alot of examples with that

Comment: Types excluded.  `while (file >> d) v.push_back (d);`

Comment: I know google has a lot of examples but I continue to get "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0" when I run

Comment: show also an example of the file structure

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: Did you allocate correctly doubles? If you just created a vector its size is 0 there's no automatic growth like some high-level languages.

Comment: Just noticed that you are not incrementing x in the code snippet you provided.  also as Chad suggests, push_back is probably a better bet here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things obvious from the code I see (already mentioned in comments):

1. You don't increment `x`.
2. Even w/o increment, you access `doubles[x]` with x==0 when doubles has no elements. That's undefined behavior. You need to allocate elements ahead of time or use `push_back` to grow vector as needed.

Answer (score 4):

You have created an **empty vector** here.

```
vector<double> doubles;
```

And here, you are indexing into the vector, as if it's **not empty**.  It's still empty and you are accessing an invalid element.

```
doubles[x]=a;
```

Change that code to use [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

```
doubles.push_back(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have submitted has a few issues.  As stated by others, you have instantiated an empty `std::vector` and your code does assignments onto an index that does not exist.  Since your problem revolves around an unknown amount of elements (dynamic size), use the `push_back` method of `std::vector`.  I would advise you not convert from `float` to `double` through `a`.  You know the data is a `double` and you want to store it as a `double`, so use `double`.  Since this is just a piece of your code, you can utilize a `for` loop to make `double a` scope bound to the loading of the data.

Your code can be rewritten into:

```
std::ifstream myfile("/Users/jaychinnaswamy/Documents/PMHistory.txt");
std::vector<double> doubles;
for (double a; myfile >> a;) {
    doubles.push_back(a);
}
```

However, if you don't require data verification, you know the file contains only doubles, and you really just want to import the numbers, then use the range constructor for `std::vector` to read the file for you via `std::istream_iterator`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile("/Users/jaychinnaswamy/Documents/PMHistory.txt");
    std::vector<double> doubles{(std::istream_iterator<double>(myfile)),
                                 std::istream_iterator<double>()};
}
```

Pay special attention to the `()` around the first iterator argument of the `std::vector` range constructor. Without the `()` will result in syntactic ambiguity, also known as [the "most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).