# Read ASCII into array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ascii

I am new to C++ and could not get a way to do this apparently simple task.
I have an ascii file containing only tab separated numbers, something like:

```
1    2    5    6

8    9    1    3 

5    9    2    3
```

I need to simply load this line by line into an array using c++. What is an easy way to do it?
Thanks in advance!
Niccolo

Comment: Are you having problems reading from a file? Or is it a problem with arrays? Have you tried anything?

Comment: also, what compiler do you use? Might be relevant for c++11/14 features...

Comment: hei! i am using visual studio 2012. i am not very experienced with reading files with c++ so i dont really have a clue from where to start...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c   instead of printf, assign the number to your array. You need to declare the array size beforehand, or store the information about how many numbers there are in the first line of the file. Normally, if you "don't know" how many elements there are to load, you use lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment because I don't have 50 reputation yet, but I'll try to help you as best as I can through an answer.

This requires basic understanding of C++ and loops. Best way I see, would be to use also `std::vector` (since you mentioned C++).

- `std::fstream`
- `std::vector<char>`
- `char`
- `std::noskipws`
- `vector.push_back`

Sample program flow:

1. Open input stream
2. Check if it's open
3. Loop through the input, character by character and make use of `std::noskipws`
4. While inside the loop, use vector.push_back
5. Remember to close the input stream

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //Use std::fstream for opening and reading the file.txt
    std::fstream Input("file.txt", std::fstream::in);

    //If the input stream is open...
    if(Input.is_open())
    {
        //...Create variables
        char ch;
        std::vector<char> cVector;

        //Loop trough the Input, character by characted and make use of std::noskipws
        while(Input >> std::noskipws >> ch) 
        {
            //Push the char ch to the vector
            cVector.push_back(ch);
        }

        //This is for looping through the vector, and printing the content as it is
        for(auto i : cVector)
        {
            std::cout << i;
        }

        //Remember to close the input
        Input.close();
    }

    //Prevent application from closing instantly
    std::cin.ignore(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully I helped you, and this solves the problem. But next time would be appreciated if you could explain what you are having trouble with, and what you have tried.

Regards,
Okkaaj

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help! I tried it but it exists the loop at the first run...?
thanks again