# How to convert an array of ASCII codes to int C++

Tags: c++, file, text, ascii

First of all, i would like to read from plain text, i read hundreds of webpages about it and i just can't make it. I want to read every byte of the file and every two byte is a number what i want to store.

I want to read: 10 20.

I get: ASCII code of 1, ASCII code of 0, ASCII code of space etc. etc.

I tried several things, like stream.get, or stream.read, tried to convert with atoi but then i can't concatenate the two digits, i tried sprintf but all of them failed.

Comment: Converting ascii, i.e. text, to ints has been successfully done with scanf for 45 years or so. scanf is safe to use with C++. Alternatively you can use the fancy C++ streams which have only been in use for 30 years or so. Perhaps you read into a char variable? Try to do `int i1, i2; cin >> i1 >> i2;`.

Comment: Why not simply something like `int x,y; cin >> x >> y;`? It's totally unclear what your problems actually are, improve your question please.

Comment: And yes, include a better wording of your input and expected output. Best show a sample program and transcribe a sample session running it.

Comment: Show us the simplest code that you think should work but doesn't.

Comment: std::istringstream iss(text);
 
 for (i = 0; i < textsize; i++)
 { 
  iss >> std::noskipws >> numbers[i];
  
  if (numbers[i] == ' ')
  {
   printf("SPACE");
  }
  else if(numbers[i] == '\n')
  {
   printf("ENTER");
  }
  else
  {
  }
  printf("%u ", numbers[i]);
 }

Comment: And this code shoudln't work but this is all i can think of. I just don't know how to read n digit decimals separated by spaces and an enter after a line. I want to detect when an enter occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Array of ASCII codes:

```
 char ASCII[] = "10 20";
```

Convert to integer variables:

```
 std::istringstream iss(ASCII);

 int x,y;

 iss >> x >> y;
```

Done.

Here's the working sample: http://ideone.com/y8ZRGs

Comment: It looks pretty simple but i have two problems. My array is dynamic, and even if i want to try out this code:

Error 1 error C2079: 'iss' uses undefined class 'std::basic_istringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
Error 2 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char [6]' to 'int'

My code:
char stuff[] = "11 12";
std::istringstream iss(stuff);

Comment: @Asd Improve your question please, to get better answers. How should I know without more context, what your real problems are? Anyways my answer is pretty generic, and should be applicable for your uee case. Try `; std::istringstream iss(std::string(stuff)); ` and add the required headers with `#include <sstream>` and `#include <string>`.

Comment: Code:

 int x, y;
 char ASCII[] = "10 20";

 std::istringstream iss(std::string(ASCII));

 iss >> x >> y;

Errors:

Error 1 error C2296: '>>' : illegal, left operand has type 'std::istringstream (__cdecl *)(std::string)'

 4 IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: @Asd Works for me, put a link to my answer.  Your problems seem to stem from elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you it was my fault, i didn't include istream. Now i got it working and implemented to my case but i have a huge problem now.

I want to detect spaces and enters. If i do like this i lose this and i lose the structure. I want to store values between spaces and if an enter occurs i want to store the next line in a different place. :/

Comment: @asd That's a different question, and I'm not going to guide you through. Stack Overflow isn't meant as your personal help desk, and this current question of yours is already not fitting well for the format desired here. Go read a good book, before asking here please!

Comment: I have found a similar thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744820/read-ascii-into-array-in-c?rq=1

Its the same exact input but the answer there isn't working it gives the same ascii code...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with your own code, there are only two things you need to be able to do.

First, you need to convert from the ASCII code of a digit to the number it represents. This is as simple as subtracting `'0'`.

Second, you need to convert from the numerical value of each digit of a two digit number to the number that represents. This is simple -- if `T` is the tens place and `U` is the units, it's `10T + U`.

So, for example:

```
int twoDigitNumber (char tens, char units)
{
    return 10 * (tens - '0') + (units - '0');
}
```