# Printing data from a text file using Cpp in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I simply want to print out a set of integers, that are written down one on each line in a text file.
Since I am using Linux, I cannot seem to use convenient functions like getch() and getline()

Please read my code below and tell me what I need to change to see the integers in the text file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream fp;
    fp.open("/home/Documents/C/Codeblocks/test1.txt", ios::in);

    int c;
    if(!fp)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot open file\n";
        return 1;
    }
    while(fp)
    {
        fp.get(c);
        cout << c;
    }
    //while ((c = getline(fp) != EOF))
      //  printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: `getline` will work also on linux. It's standard C++. Just pass the right arguments to it. (Hint: getline does not return as you expected)

Comment: Well, not on Codeblocks at least...

Answer (score 2):

Really nice way to read things from file is by using streams. By using them you can easily read numbers seperated with whitespaces (e.g. newline, spaces, etc.) simply by using `>>` operator. Please read the first answer in following article, it suits perfectly to your issue:

[Read Numeric Data from a Text File in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c)

What you could to do is

```
int c;
while (fp >> c)
{
    cout << c << " ";
}
```

Also, you don't necessarily have to split declaration and definition of `fstream fp;` variable in your case. Simply put

```
fstream myfile("/home/Documents/C/Codeblocks/test1.txt", ios::in);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int c;
    ifstream fp("/home/Documents/C/Codeblocks/test1.txt");
    if (!fp.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Cannot open file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    while (fp >> c)
        cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```