# Read PPM files RGB values C++

Tags: c++, ppm

I'm trying read from a PPM file.
I want to read the first, second and third number from each row, in [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtiSh.png), but I don´t know how to read the lines.

This is what I have so far:

```
for (int y = 4; y <= HEIGHT; y++) { // i think it has to start on row 4 
    for (int x = 1; x <= WIDTH; x++) { // and x from 1
         int i = 4;

         int r = CurrentR(i);
         int g = CurrentG(i);
         int b = CurrentB(i);
         i++;
    }   
}

int CurrentR(int I) {
    return // the first number in row xy
}
int CurrentG(int I) {
    return // the second number in row xy
}
int CurrentB(int I) {
    return // the third number in row xy
}
```

Comment: you want to convert PPM to BMP ?

Comment: @tobi303 no, i want to store the RGB values of a PPM file.

Comment: and you want to store the RGB values in `img` ? what is `img`?

Comment: @tobi303 Don´t mind that. I just need to know what needs to be in the CurrentR(), CurrentG() and CurrentB() functions.

Comment: I totally dont understand your code, but it cannot work like this. You pass the same parameters for `x=5,y=6` and `x=6,y=5`

Comment: you will have to read the file sequentially, you dont have random access (unless you read the whole content of the file into memory)

Comment: and btw "Dont´t mind that." doesnt help to answer questions in general

Comment: @tobi303 hmm, you´re right. I should probably use an int counting each time the x for-loop runs. That would probably fix that.

Comment: No, you should probably read line by line of the file....

Comment: Do you know how to open a file and read some numbers from it? (suggested reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would suggest you to do it:

```
struct RGB {
    int R,B,G;
}
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream &in,RGB& rgb){
    in >> rgb.R;
    in >> rgb.G;
    in >> rgb.B;
    return in;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out,RGB& rgb){
    out << rgb.R << " ";
    out << rgb.G << " ";
    out << rgb.B << std::endl;
    return out;
}


int main(){
    std::string filename = "test.txt";
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    if(file.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) { std::getline(file,line); }
        RGB rgb;
        for (int i=0;i<LINES_TO_READ;i++) {
            file >> rgb;
            std::cout << rgb;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but it´s the "read the three numbers" part i need help with. Your way may be a better way, but i am very much a beginner, so if you could help with getting the ifstream going that would be better i think. I read the link you posted, and i didnt understand much.

Comment: This also doesn't account for the formatting info that ppm files start with.