# Need help trying to insert numbers from the keyboard into a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, input, console

I am writing a class that holds an RGB color. I have been trying a bunch of different things to try to insert the numbers from the keyboard, but nothing is working. I have four different operators overloaded because that's what I need to do for the assignment. 
This is my main page.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "color.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;

string printColor(Color c);
void printBox(vector<Color> box);


int main() {


    vector<Color> box;
    Color a;
    cout << "Enter three ints.";
    cin >> a;
    box.push_back(a);
        //box.push_back(b);
        //box.push_back(Color(100,100,100));
        //box.push_back(Color(10,10,125));
        //box.push_back(Color(150,1,150));

    printBox(box);

    sort(box.begin(), box.end());

    printBox(box);

    printColor(a);


    return 0;
}

void printBox(vector<Color> box) {
    vector<Color>::iterator it; //iterators are pointers
    cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (it = box.begin(); it != box.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
string printColor(Color c) {
    char temp [8];
    sprintf(temp,"#%02x%02x%02x",c.red, c.green, c.blue);
    return string(temp);

}
```

Here is my Source file

```
#include "color.h"
using namespace std;
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Color &b){
    out<< "Red: " << b.red << " Green: " << b.green << " Blue: " << b.blue;
    return out;
}
bool operator<(const Color &a, const Color &b){
    return a.red < b.red && a.blue < b.blue && a.green < b.green;
}
bool operator==(const Color &a, const Color &b){
    bool result;
    result = a.red == b.red && a.blue == b.blue && a.green == b.green;
    return result;
}
```

Here is my header file

```
#ifndef COLOR_H_
#define COLOR_H_
#include <iostream>

struct Color {
int red;
int green;
int blue;
Color(int _red, int _green, int _blue){
    red = _red;
    green = _green;
    blue = _blue;
}
};

bool operator<(const Color &a, const Color &b);
bool operator==(const Color &a, const Color &b);
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Color &b);
#endif /* COLOR_H_ */
```

Comment: what did you try to get the numbers from the keyboard? Maybe I missed it, but I didnt find any code related to this

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33423425/4117728) is about reading rgb values from a file. Not exactly what you want, but maybe it helps

Comment: I took it out because it would only give me errors. Sorry I should have kept it in. I was basically trying everything I could find on the internet about using cin to put numbers in a vector.

Comment: Thanks that will probably help me once I get the issue solved.

Comment: Do you have the code for printBox and printColor?

Comment: you actually removed all code that is relevant for the question and the one you show is not relevant for the question. Its nice to know that you implemented four operators, but none of them will help you to read numbers from the keyboard and put them into a vector. Atm it is not even clear what is your "issue"

Comment: Anytime I use a cin I get this error. no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'Color')

Comment: look at the link I gave you above, in that answer, there is an example of how to implement that operator

Comment: @benderbot2004 Side note:  That `operator <` is not going to work with `std::sort`.  It fails to follow a `strict weak ordering`.  There are cases where false is returned for both `a < b` and for the same two items `b < a`.

Comment: @benderbot2004 So where is your `operator >>` in your post?  Also, you did not `include <ostream>` anywhere, but you're using `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to fetch types from `std::cin` more intuitively.  FYI, you can "close" `std::cin` in the command line by pressing `CTRL+D`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

class Color {
    int R, G, B;
public:
    Color() = default; // Required for iterator-support
    Color(int r, int g, int b) : R{r}, G{g}, B{b} {};
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Color&);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Color& c)
{
    std::array<int, 3> rgb{};
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{in}, 3, rgb.begin());
    std::tie(c.R, c.G, c.B) = std::tie(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Color> colors{
        std::istream_iterator<Color>{std::cin}
      , std::istream_iterator<Color>{}
        };
    std::cout << colors.size() << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b0e1d8ab5566457)