# C++ - How to read vector<bool> from file with delimiter

Tags: c++

My aim is to read n `vector<bool>` delimited by the separator '|' from a text file. An example of the text file content could be this:

`0111110001|0111110110|00|11001111100|1100110100|`

Is this possible to do? Can you give me any hints please? I'm just starting with C++.

Comment: Do the tokens separated by `|` represent one `std::vector<bool>` each?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Have you tried anything? For instance using an `ifstream` to read in some data. Post some code and you will get help. But we can't do your homework...

Comment: @RSahu Yes, each `std::vector<bool>` is separated by `|` . In the above example, there are 5 `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: This is too broad, have a look at some examples like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c then come back when you have tried something.

Comment: @SaintSanto, read one character at a time using `istream::get()`. If the character is `0` or `1`, add a suitable value to a vector. If the character is `|`, switch the vector to which you add the items.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ifstream fp("myfile.txt");
    if(!fp) {
        cerr << "Failed to open input file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    vector<vector<bool>> lists;
    lists.push_back(vector<bool>());

    char ch;
    while(fp.good()) {
        fp >> ch;
        switch(ch) {
        case '0':
            lists.back().push_back(false);
            break;
        case '1':
            lists.back().push_back(true);
            break;
        case '|':
            lists.push_back(vector<bool>());
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```