# How do I read a line of 12 numbers from a file and store it into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, int

The file is a text file named TotalMonthlyRainfall2014.txt and it contains the following in a single line:

```
0.33 0.41 1.45 1.74 3.40 3.26 0.98 4.34 0.06 2.09 2.13 1.13
```

I want to read the numbers from the file and store them into a single array called monthRain. so monthRain[0] will be 0.33, monthRain[1] will be 0.41, and so forth.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//global variable
const int months = 12;
const string FILENAME = "TotalMonthlyRainfall2014.txt";

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;        //input file stream
    float monthRain[months];

                    //open the file
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    //loop through and get data from file
    for (int i = 0; i < months && (inFile >> monthRain); i++)
    {
       cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << monthRain[i];
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

I guess the question is how to properly store the numbers into array monthRain.

Comment: And what issues are you having with this code specifically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c duplicate question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read from numbers from file into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850600/how-to-read-from-numbers-from-file-into-array)

Comment: you simply ignored the comments asking for a mcve and posted the exact same question again. Why?

Comment: I was trying to clean up the way the question looked. This is my first time posting so I'm not even sure how to format questions properly. I'm not sure what an mcve is.

Comment: OK I tried to format and edit it as much as possible to fit the regulation.

Comment: You may start declaring the array: `const int months = 12; float monthRain[months];` then read the file putting the data in it `for ( int i = 0; i < months  &&  cin >> monthRain[i]; ++i ) { cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << monthRain[i] << '\n'; }`.

Comment: @Francisco You edited it too much, you left out the `monthRain` variable declaration.

Comment: @Bob__ Post that as an answer.

Comment: The problem with Bob's answer is it asks for an input from the keyboard into monthRain instead of getting the floats from the txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your problem. It will parse all rows and place each line in a string stream. It then parses the string stream and streams the elements into doubles. It should work for any combination of rows and column elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(){

// Open file
ifstream fileStream;
fileStream.open("myIniFile.txt");

// Initialize variables
string lineString;
int counter=0;
vector<vector<double> > myData; // Matrix which holds all data
vector<double> myLine; // Temporary vector to hold each row
double currentNumber;

// Read file
while(!fileStream.eof()){
    ++counter;        
    getline(fileStream,lineString); // Stream this line in a string
    if (lineString!=""){ // If empty, exit            
        cout<<"Line #"<<counter<<" : "; // Print
        cout<<lineString<<endl;         // output            
        stringstream myS_stream(lineString);
        while(myS_stream>>currentNumber){ // Important as a simple break condition will read the last element twice
            cout<<"\tFound double number in string stream : "<< currentNumber<<endl;
            myLine.push_back(currentNumber);
        }
        myData.push_back(myLine);
        myLine.clear();
    }
}
fileStream.close(); // Close file

// Print your data
cout<<"\nMy data is : "<<endl;
for (auto row : myData){
    cout<<"\t";
    for (auto element : row){
        cout<<" "<<element;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

// Convert to the format you want, but I suggest using std::vector
// if you can help it
double *monthRain = &myData.at(0)[0];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right question for your answer?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's more general, but I think if one is to go through the trouble of doing this, they might as well have code they can reuse. Just realised I didn't provide the conversion to the format the OP wants: the c-array can always be retrieved from the vector: double *monthRain = &myData.at(0)[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
// Headers
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Global variables
const int months = 12;
const string FILENAME = "TotalMonthlyRainfall2014.txt";

int main()
{
ifstream inFile;        //input file stream
float monthRain[months];

                   //open the file
inFile.open(FILENAME.c_str());
//loop through and get data from file
for (int i = 0; i < months && (inFile >> monthRain[i]); i++)
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << monthRain[0] << '\n';
}

inFile.close();
}
```

Progress! Now whenever 0 is in:
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << monthRain[0] << '\n';
it outputs 0.33 which is correct, but it outputs it 12 times.

Comment: You have to use `monthRain[i]` instead of `monthRain[0]`.

Comment: Think on `monthRain[0]` for a while.