# C++ array output file results in -memory address

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So, I copied a program from my textbook to give it a test and am having output problems. The program is simple:

(When i run the program VS says the program is out of date; I don't know if the problem may be there.)

```
//This program reads data from a file into an array
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int Array_size = 10; //array size
    int numbers[Array_size];  //array with 10 elements
    int count = 0;   //loop counter variable
    ifstream inputFile;   //input file stream object

    //opent the file
    inputFile.open("C:/TenNumbers.txt");

    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //read the numbers from the file into the array
    while (count < Array_size && inputFile >> numbers[count])
        count++;

    //close the file
    inputFile.close();

    //display the numbers read
    cout << "The numbers are: ";
    for (count = 0; count < Array_size; count++)
        cout << numbers[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

The output is:

[image]

and the console debug is:

> 'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\project7.3\Debug\project7.3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'project7.3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   The thread 0x6e44 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x68ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x5978 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x56ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[7220] project7.3.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Here is the contents of the text file in notepad++. I changed the encoding from UTF8 to ANSI based on info found online:

//This file supports the program7.3 in visual studio 2015
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110

Comment: You're printing `"file open"` if the file couldn't be opened. You probably need to look up the concept of *working directory*.

Comment: Thank you, that was just one of many things I tried while reading through solutions. I forgot to take it out.

Comment: Your leaving it in at least shows that the file couldn't be opened, even though the message is wrong.

Comment: Why did you get rid of the file check?  You should always check that the file was opened before continuing.

Comment: I don't know what numbers you *expect* to be output. As far as I can tell from your screen-shot of the output, there are 10 numbers. Is the output problem that you did not expect *those* numbers? I feel like it might be that you're not reading the integers as integers, but rather strings. Does the solution presented in [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14517130/5209610) fix output problems?

Answer (score 1):

The message in the following block is misleading.

```
if (!inputFile)
{
    cout << "file open" << endl;
}
```

It should be

```
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
```

After that, you proceed to read the data anyway when you should bail out.

```
if (!inputFile)
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILUIRE;
}
```

You are getting bogus data since nothing is being read from the file.

And then, you proceed to display all the data. You need to display only the data that were successfully read. Use:

```
//display the numbers read
cout << "The numbers are: ";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    cout << numbers[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you. I put the file directly in the C drive and applied the changes you suggested but it is still outputting the wonky numbers.

Comment: @ShaunCampbell, that does not make sense. Please update your post with the additional information.

Comment: I think what @RSahu meant by "update with... additional information" is that you should include updated code & the actual text file that you are trying to write into an array, and then display.

Comment: @ShaunCampbell, that edit is not good. You have updated the post in such a way that my answer does not make sense at all :) You need to leave the original post and add the updated code at the end.

Comment: Oh sorry, first timer.

Comment: @ShaunCampbell, that's OK. Every community has its etiquette that is not obvious at first glance.

Comment: I found the solution. I was having an encoding problem. While I saved the text file as ANSII in Notepad++ it did not apply it because I was not using Notepad as administrator. I noticed the file was still in UTF-8 format and changed it to ANSII as administrator and it fixed the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @ShaunCampbell, doesn't it feel great to finally have cracked the problem?? Happy programming.