# heelp me read nos from file in c++?

Tags: c++

wanted to read only nums from file & store them in array.i don't know file handling. please help me out.

```
#include iostream conio.h
#stdio.h string fstream;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

 ifstream myfile("ashishdata.txt");//file open

char c;
char arr[100];
int i=0;
// read data from file

while (myfile.get(c))
{
    if(isdigit(c) || c=='.' )
    {
    arr[i] = c;
    i++;
    }
}
arr[i]='\0';//mark end of array
myfile.close();//file closed
int k;
k=strlen(arr);
//parsing string
int newarr[100];
int m=0;
string(s);
for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
{
    s.erase();
    while(arr[i] != '.')
    {
        s+=arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    newarr[m]=atoi(s.c_str());
    m++;
}

newarr[m]='\0';
//printing newarray
i=0;
while(newarr[i]!='\0')
{
    cout<<newarr[i]<<'\t';
    i++;
}
cout<<endl;

getch();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: also learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`filename.txt`:
4545.454
sds
65.65.6.65656

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char c;
  char arr[100];
  size_t i = 0;
  // read data from file
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("filename.txt", ios::in);
  while (!myfile.eof()) {
    myfile >> c;
    if (isdigit(c) || c == '.') {
      arr[i] = c;
      i++;
    }
  }
  arr[i] = '\0';  // mark end of array
  myfile.close();  // file closed
  size_t k = strlen(arr);
  // parsing string
  int newarr[100];
  int m = 0;
  string s;
  for (i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
    s.erase();
    while (arr[i] != '.') {
      s += arr[i++];
    }
    newarr[m++] = atoi(s.c_str());
  }

  newarr[m] = '\0';
  // printing newarray
  i = 0;
  while (newarr[i] != '\0') {
    cout << newarr[i++] << '\t';
  }
  return 0;
}
```