# Count the number of elements in txt file

Tags: c++

I have an assignment like this:

```
/*
-   Read an input text file (.txt) contain one line to store an array of integer:
Input.txt
4 1 2 -100 -3 10 98 7
-   Write SumList function to sum all integer data of the list
-   Write a function to find the max of all integer data
-   ...
*/
```

My question is how to count the number of numbers in the txt file to use 
/for (int i = 0; i < N; i++), N is number of numbers in file/ for reading the file. Or is there any way else to read this file without initializing N?
Thank you!

Comment: Does input text file contain only one line of array of integers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Numeric Data from a Text File in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c)

Comment: Yes. It contain only 1 line of integers

Answer (score 1):

Your real question is: how to read a file word by word.

I believe that you've known what file stream is, so here is the code:

```
fstream file("yourfile.txt", ios::in); 
std::string word;
while (file >> word)
{
    // convert word to int
}
```

Now the next question is: how to convert a string to int. I hope you can figure it out on your own --- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

---

Also, this would be easier: (Thanks to @Fei Xiang)

```
int i;
while (file >> i)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Can I use atoi?

Comment: Why not just input into an int? Also, some explanation on `while(file >> word)` would be nice.

Comment: @KhaNguyen  `atoi` is banned by your professor? How about `std::stringstream`?

Comment: Atoi is not banned by my prof.

Comment: Also, my friend request me to using count pHead to pTail. Can I ask for detail about that solution?

Comment: @KhaNguyen you can use the second piece of code, it is easier because you don't need to convert it anymore. "pHead to pTail"? I don't what it is.

Comment: That is Link List. pHead is the first node, and pTail is the last node, which point to NUL.

Comment: @KhaNguyen  So it is about Data Structure, you can google it. You are asking how to read file, data structure is about how you storing your data. Totally different things.