# Why is my string empty when taking input from file?

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream, getline

I have a huge file full of numbers (2 billion). So this is a file splitter that splits my file in groups of 100000 numbers. but this is returning empty files full of spaces and enters. I even tried to change the data type of the variable. I am struck. please suggest.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("prime.txt");

        unsigned long long int curr;
        unsigned long long int x = 0;
        string li;
        int count;
        while (getline(ifs, li))
        {
            count ++;
        }
        ifs.seekg(ios::beg);
        string v;
        while (curr < count)
        {
            x++;
            std::string file = to_string(x) ;
            std::string filename = "splitted\\"+file+ ".txt";
            std::ofstream ofile (filename.c_str());

            while (curr < 100000*x )
            {

                ifs >> v ;
                ofile << v << "\n";
                curr++;
            }
            ofile.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `curr` is uninitialised. Is `v` supposed to be a `char`? Shouldn't it be a numeric type large enough to hold your numbers or at least a string?

Comment: Not the cause of your problem but counting the lines before you start seems unnecessary and inefficient and may cause problems as you aren't then reading line by line but using the line count as your termination condition

Comment: In addition to `ifs.seekg` you probably also need to clear the steam state

Comment: there's also no reason to explicitly close ofile since it will be closed in its destructure

Comment: how to clear the steam state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Numeric Data from a Text File in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c)

Comment: i cannot say because i didnt understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 uninitialised variables, `count` and `curr`, your compiler should have warned you about these. If it didn't make sure you have enabled compiler warnings.

After the last `getline` in your initial while loop fails the stream will have the `fail` and `eof` flags set. Due to the stream not being in the `good` state all further operations on it will fail so your `seekg` will be ignored as will all your reads. To fix this call `ifs.clear();` before your `seekg`.

As you don't seem to need the line count anywhere pre-calculating it is unnecessary and as you are then not reading the file in lines it will lead to incorrect behaviour if your file has more than one value on a line. Your code can be simplified to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("prime.txt");
    if (!ifs)
    {
        std::cout << "error opening input file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int64_t fileNumber = 0;
    int64_t fileCount = 0;
    std::ofstream ofile;
    while (ifs)
    {
        if (!ofile.is_open() || (fileCount >= 100000))
        {
            ofile.close();
            fileCount = 0;
            fileNumber++;
            std::string file = to_string(fileNumber);
            std::string filename = "splitted\\" + file + ".txt";
            ofile.open(filename.c_str());
            if (!ofile)
            {
                std::cout << "error opening output file\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
        std::string value;
        if (ifs >> value) {
            ofile << value << "\n";
            fileCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the variables curr and count are initialized in 12th and 15th line of my code.

Comment: No, they're declared, not initialised

Comment: also each of the numbers in my 'primes.txt' are in a new line.